# Java 8 wildcard type cannot be instantiated directly

Tags: generics, java-8, compiler-errors

Java 8 here. I have the following generic class:

```
public class Memory<T> {
    private String moniker;
    private Date timestamp;
    private T data;

    // constructors, getters & setters, etc.
}
```

I'm trying to build a non-generic `MemoryFactory` like so:

```
public class MemoryFactory {
    public Memory<?> createMemory(Object data, String moniker) {
        Date now = new Date();

        return new Memory<?>(moniker, now, data);
    }
}
```

However I get a compiler error on the return statement for that `<?>` usage:

> Wildcard type '?' cannot be instantiated directly

So again, I want the `MemoryFactory` to be non-generic, and allow me to make the following calls:

```
Memory<Fizz> fizzMemory = memoryFactory.createMemory(new Fizz(), "fizz1");
Memory<String> strMemory = memoryFactory.createMemory("SOMETHING", "str1");
Memory<Buzz> buzzMemory = memoryFactory.createMemory(new Buzz(11, true), "buzz1");
```

**What do I need to do to accomplish this and fix the compiler error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This signature won't allow you to make these calls anyway, no matter what you do in the implementation, because `Memory<?>` is a *supertype* of `Memory<Fizz/Buzz/AnythingElse>`. If you had `public Object createMemory(...)`, you wouldn't expect to assign its result to `Memory<Fizz>`, would you? This is no different.

To allow these calls, you *have* to make `createMemory` (not `MemoryFactory`) generic:

```
public <T> Memory<T> createMemory(T data, String moniker) {
    Date now = new Date();

    return new Memory<>(moniker, now, data); // or new Memory<T>
}
```